# Is there any way to define maximum and minimum date for a date column of a kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo grid with in-cell editing and a pair of date columns. I want to specify a maximum and a minimum date for the datepickers inside the cell the user is editing, but it doesn't seem to exist any property for that.

I tried to do it with templates:

```html
<kendo-grid-column field="StartDate" title="Start Date">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <kendo-datepicker
        format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
        [(ngModel)]="dataItem"
        ></kendo-datepicker>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

But I'm getting a bunch of errors. How can I make this work?

**EDIT:** I created a stackblitz example based on one of the in-cell editing examples that I found in the documentation:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewvsh5

Here, I discovered that I wasn't specifying the property ngModel has to connect to:

```
[(ngModel)]="dataItem"
```

Should be:

```
[(ngModel)]="dataItem.Date"
```

Ok, I changed it, but now, when I click on the date cell, instead of appearing a datepicker, it appears a regular input. Please, check this part in the components template, it's where the problem is:

```html
<!-- This doesn't work -->
<kendo-grid-column field="Date" title="Date">
    <ng-template
        kendoGridCellTemplate
        let-dataItem
        let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
        let-isEdited="isEdited"
        *ngIf="editingDateCell"
    >
        <kendo-datepicker [(ngModel)]="dataItem.Date"></kendo-datepicker>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template
        kendoGridCellTemplate
        let-dataItem
        let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
        let-isEdited="isEdited"
        *ngIf="!editingDateCell"
    >
        {{ dataItem.Date | date }}
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT II:** All the solutions so far show the datepicker inside the cell. That's fine, I know how to do it. The problem is that before the user clicks to edit the cell, that cell must be like a label, when the user clicks on that label, it has to become a datepicker. If the user changes the date and clicks away, the grid has to know that the data has been updated and act accordly. In summary, I need to preserve the in-cell editing behavior.

Comment: What errors do you get? Also an example (e.g. via https://stackblitz.com/) showing the problem(s) would be highly appreciated and will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the min and max date picker properties. Please refer to [this API reference link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/date-ranges/) for date picker min max example.
Also refer to [this forum link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-datepicker-in-kendogridedittemplate) for an example of a date picker column template.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <form novalidate #myForm="ngForm">
          <kendo-grid
              [data]="view | async"
              [height]="533"
              [pageSize]="gridState.take" [skip]="gridState.skip" [sort]="gridState.sort"
              [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true"
              (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)"
              (edit)="editHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)"
              (save)="saveHandler($event)" (remove)="removeHandler($event)"
              (add)="addHandler($event)"
              [navigable]="true"
            >
            <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
                <button kendoGridAddCommand type="button">Add new</button>
            </ng-template>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
                <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="dataItem.ProductName" kendoGridFocusable name="ProductName" class="k-textbox" required/>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="date" title="Date" format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}">
                <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
                    <kendo-datepicker  
                    [format]="'yyyy-MM-dd'" 
                    [(ngModel)]="dataItem.date" 
                    [min]="min"
                    [max]="max"
                    name="date"></kendo-datepicker>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-command-column title="command" width="220">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew">
                    <button kendoGridEditCommand type="button" class="k-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button kendoGridRemoveCommand type="button">Remove</button>
                    <button kendoGridSaveCommand type="button" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">{{ isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update' }}</button>
                    <button kendoGridCancelCommand type="button">{{ isNew ? 'Discard changes' : 'Cancel' }}</button>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-command-column>
          </kendo-grid>
      </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public min: Date = new Date(2018, 2, 10);
    public max: Date = new Date(2018, 11, 25);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, but thanks for the `kendoGridEditTemplate` hint. I could solve it thanks to that directive.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, what I had to do is to use the `kendoGridEditTemplate` instead of the `kendoGridCellTemplate` and use `[formControl]` instead of `[(value)]` or `[(ngModel)]`. If you follow the [example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/) found in the documentation, and you want to add a custom date column so you have full access to the datepicker's properties, the markup to add is this one:

```html
<kendo-grid-column
  field="StartDate"
  title="Start Date"
  [format]="{ date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }"
>
  <ng-template
    kendoGridEditTemplate    <!-- Important -->
    let-column="column"
    let-formGroup="formGroup"
  >
    <kendo-datepicker
      format="dd/MM/yyyy"
      [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)"    <!-- Important -->
      [min]="minimumDate"
    >
    </kendo-datepicker>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a minimum and maximum of a datepicker use `[min]` and `[max]`. See [this demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/date-ranges/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example code that does what you require:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
       <p>Date</p>
       <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="date" [format]="{ date: 'long' }">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                <kendo-datepicker [(value)]="dataItem.date" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate">

                </kendo-datepicker>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
       </kendo-grid>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public minDate = new Date(2018, 4, 1);
    public maxDate = new Date(2018, 4, 31);

    const products = [{
       "ProductID": 1,
       "ProductName": "Chai",
       "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
       "Discontinued": true,
       date: new Date("2018-05-05T00:00:00-05:00")
     }, {
       "ProductID": 2,
       "ProductName": "Chang",
       "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
       "Discontinued": false,
       date: new Date("2018-05-07T00:00:00-05:00")
     }
    ];

    public gridData: any[] = products.map(item => {
      item.date = new Date(item.date);
      return item;
    });
}
```